# Javascripts post value href onclick

Tags: html

Hi need help how to solve the following:
need help to advice required javascript to post value with href action ? 
if yes, any sample for the javascript?

```
    <div class="row">
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="navbar-header">
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="@("/WWeb".FromRoot())">Home</a>
</div>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <form id="form1" action="/FAANN/ANNStat" name="postlink" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="pdata" Value="@Model.D_stock">

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a style="font-size:12px;margin-right:5px;" href="#">Summary >></a></li>

        <li> <a style="font-size:12px;margin-right:12px;" href="@("/FAANN/ANNStat".FromRoot())" onclick=" ">Statement </a> </li>

        <li class="active"><a style="font-size:12px;margin-right:12px;" href="#">BS</a></li>

        <li><a style="font-size:12px;margin-right:12px;" href="@("/FAANN/ANNCF".FromRoot())" onclick="mypost();" >Cash Flow</a></li>

        <li><a style="font-size:12px;margin-right:12px;" href="@("/FAOwnDaily/FAOwnDaily".FromRoot())" onclick="mypost();" >Top 10</a></li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">              
        <li><a style="font-size:12px;" ref="/WWeb/Account/LogOff">LogOff</a></li>
    </ul>
    </form>     
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: A r u asking how to pass the parameter value through url?  like `url = new URL("http://localhost/index.php?lat="+lat+"&long"+lon);`

Comment: yes. to pass value.

Comment: U can pass after putting question mark and to add various variable u have to add '&' symbol. See the earlier comment

Comment: sorry, i can't get it. the post value is a dynamic data and i have display in existing page. I wish to post that value to the HTML Page in click on.

Comment: i manage to do with submit button but i have no idea how should i handle when remove the button from the page this my code:         <form id="form1" action="/FAANN/ANNStat" name="postlink" method="post">
                        <input type="text" name="key" Value="@Model.D_key">
                        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
 </form>

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass values via POST using the url only. Parameters added to the URL (/path?key=value&... syntax) are GET Parameters. POST Data is added to body of the the HTTP Request, so not part of the URL.

To post data to the server you can use an `XMLHttpRequest` like so:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', '/<url>');
    xhr.send(<data here>);
```

Or you can use a form like that:

```
<form action="/<url>" method="post" id="form">
    <input type="hidden" name="<key>" value="<value>" />
</form>
```

followed by such an JS:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var form = document.getElementById('form');
    //adding more data to the form by appending more
    //inout fields
    form.submit();
}
```

I hope that helps.

**EDIT**

To POST on click:

```
<a href="someval">Txt</a>

window.onload = function () {
    var form = document.getElementById('form'),
        a = document.querySelector('a[href="someval"]');

    //variant 1 (using the "form method"):
    a.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        //modify the form here            

        form.submit();
    });

    //variant 2 (using the "xhr method"):
     a.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var xhr = new XMLHttp.. //code from above      
    });
}
```

Comment: the script is working but i wish to post the value on specify href when action onclick is taken only.

Comment: Hi philipp, TQVM your i manage to do it with variant 1.Below is my codes, please advice to help me do better.

Comment: window.onload = function () {
    var formS = document.getElementById('formS'),
        a = document.querySelector('a[href="/FAANN/ANNS"]'),
        formC = document.getElementById('formCF'),
        b = document.querySelector('a[href="/FAANN/ANNC"]'),     
     a.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
          formS.submit();
     });
     b.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
          formC.submit();
     });
}

Comment: "advice to help me do better", well, I am not sure what you want to know, or achieve, so that is kind of hard to guess. To keep the code in the answer clean it would be better to create a js fiddle.